# MySQL pulling information from multiple table issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to access information from 2 different tables and its retrieving the information but it all so pulling in user information multiple times pending how many fruits listed in table tbl_fruits.

like to be able to display user information once and pull what ever number of fruits associated with the user at the same time.

2 tables:
tbl_users:
    userid
    firstname
    lastname

tbl_fruits:
    userid
    fruit

in the example code userID 4 has 3 fruits associated with him in tbl_fruit. As you can see from the results below the user information is listed multiple times. How can I rewrite the code so that the user information is pulled once and the fruits show up 3 times.

```
$clientID = "4";

try 
{    $stmt = $dbcon1 ->query("SELECT 
                tbl_fruits.fruit,
                tbl_users.userid,
                tbl_users.firstname,
                tbl_users.lastname
               FROM tbl_users
                 LEFT JOIN tbl_fruits 
               ON tbl_fruits.userid = tbl_users.userid     
                    WHERE  tbl_users.userid = '$clientID' ");                

    $testArray = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);            
} 
catch(PDOException $e) 
{    echo $e->getMessage(); }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($testArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

results

```
array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => Apple
            [userid] => 4
            [firstname] => John
            [lastname] => Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => Orange
            [userid] => 4
            [firstname] => John
            [lastname] => Smith
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => Banana
            [userid] => 4
            [firstname] => John
            [lastname] => Smith
        )

)
```

Comment: What are you wanting it to return exactly? MySQL will always return the same columns in each row so you can't just remove them after the first... A query could be written to make it return the user once and then NULL for userid first name and last name in each subsequent row (but they'd still be there).. The other option I can think of is to use group_concat and just return one row with the fruit in comma separated or something...

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as below:

```
{    $stmt = $dbcon1 ->query("SELECT 
                count(tbl_fruits.userid) 
                tbl_users.userid,
                tbl_users.firstname,
                tbl_users.lastname
               FROM tbl_users
                 LEFT JOIN tbl_fruits 
               ON tbl_fruits.userid = tbl_users.userid     
                    WHERE  tbl_users.userid = '$clientID' 
                    GROUP BY tbl_users.userid ");
```

The `count(tbl_fruits.userid)` part counts the number of unique rows with that row's value of `tbl_fruits.userid`, while the `GROUP BY tbl_users.userid` part eliminates the duplicates.

Be sure to put an index on `tbl_users.userid` and `tbl_fruits.userid` for best performance.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the replay back but it does list the fruits associated with the user.